# Understanding CI routing and $page -> can't find .css or .js

Tags: php, codeigniter

The hardest part I'm having with learning Codeigniter is the URI and URL 'theory' if you will.

I followed the original tutorial concerning static pages, and now the code seems to mess EVERY single link up except the main nav bar, requiring me to constantly add routing parameters.  I figure I must be doing something wrong.

In my controller, I currently have this code, based off the tutorial:

```
public function view($page = 'home') {}
```

My folder structure is:

```
+ applications
  + views
    - welcome.php
    + main
      + css
      + js
      - home.php
      - about.php
      - etc.php
```

I should point out that the welcome.php page is for the login page.  On that page, a link will direct you to home.php (main/home/)

My routing code looks like this:

```
$route['default_controller'] = 'welcome';
$route['main/(:any)'] = 'main/view/$1';
$route['main/home/home'] = 'main/view/$1';
$route['404_override'] = '';
```

As you can see, I already had to put a bandaid on it with the `<code>$route['main/home/home'] = 'main/view/$1';</code>` portion, due to the fact that clicking on "home" while already on the home page would result in linking to main/home/home/ displaying my nav bar, and creating a brand new set of missing links labeled, main/home/about/

In short, I am now trying to reference a .js file and a .css file, but even though the links correctly point to /main/css/style.css it does not recognize it.

Here is my view code for the header (where i load my .css and .js)

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title><?php echo $title ?> - TownBuilder - Prototype</title>
        <link href="css/structure.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/script.js"></script>
    </head>
<body>

<header>
    <ul>
        <li> <a href="profile"><?php echo $username ?></a></li>
        <li>Account</li>
    </ul>
</header>
```

Any advice on how to set up routing so that it works correctly?

Comment: If you're trying to reference a .js file and .css file, but it's not working, please post your view code that references so we can see how you're doing it.

Comment: As an alternative, I usually place my .js and .css files in the root of the site, and simply refer to their respective directories with something like `base_url() . '/js/file.js'`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should add the css/js file on the root directory(outsite of the application folder crete a folder called css) as CI has .htaccess files that deny all access to the application folder. You can only include those files from within your scripts.

Comment: This worked.  Though I am still very confused for routing. My fault for asking too many questions at one time.

Answer (score 1):

IMHO they need to remove the route's piece from the codeigniter tutorial because it's not necessary, and it screws everyone up.

Here's the gist of how things work. First comment out all of your routes.

Controller:

```
Class FirstController extends CI_Controller {

  public function home() {
      // do stuff
      $this->load->view('home');
  }
}
```

Make sure you have a view called `home.php` in your view folder.

Then the url should be `<base_url>/controller/method`, so in this case it would be `<base_url>/FirstController/home`

Comment: Is it best practice to create a new Class for each page you want to make?  For example, create a new class for "Home" and "About" and "Etc" ?

Comment: You don't have to, but if you want your urls to be <domainname>/home/index, <domainname>/about/index you have to create a separate controller for each page. another way i've done it is to create 1 controller called site and then haev a method for each page in that controller. Your urls would then look like <domainname>/site/home and <domanname>/site/about, etc.

Comment: If you would not like the "site"-part in the example of the previous comment, you should at those routes though.  This would become `$routes['home'] = "site/home"; $routes['about'] = "site/about";`.  Urls will then become <domainname>/home and <domainname>/about.  Perhaps `$routes[(:any)] = "site/$1";` on its own  will also work, but to be sure I would have to test it first.  This would mean you could only have static pages however since everything would be routed to that controller.